# PySide: Assign accelerator to `QTextEdit`

Tags: python, qt, pyside

How do I assign an accelerator that would put focus on a `QTextEdit`? I'm a PySide newb and I tried what worked in `wxPython`, which is to make a label before the text edit and give it an accelerator, however I tried doing both `'&Title:'` and `'_Title:'` but none of them gave it an accelerator of `T` like I wanted. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the label's [setBuddy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#setBuddy) method to get the accelerator to work:

```
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel('&Title:', self)
    self.textedit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
    self.label.setBuddy(self.textedit)
```